# Unity's Particle System - shader glitch (mesh vertices reduction)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, particle-system

I have a problem on some Android devices with the particle system's rendering (weirdly enough the problem seems occur on devices with higher capabilities). The problem occurs when mesh based particles (Renderer/Renderer Mode/Mesh) are being rendered. It seems like the meshes that are being spewed out and slowly shrunk with time are being reduced ("reverse-tessellated") which results in a nasty visual effect. Does anyone know what might be the cause of this?

**UPDATE:** One thing that I've noticed is that with time - the longer the gameplay - this problem is getting worse.

**UPDATE:** What I've tried is to make one particle system bigger (around x5 times) in order to check if it will have any effect on it's rasterization. Normally particles are sized down from 1 to 0 based on their life-time. What I've noticed, after sizing them up, is that the problem does not occur anymore.

**UPDATE**: Visualisation of the problem:

Properly rendered:

[image]

Improperly rendered:

[image]

Comment: It might help if you include an image, or even better a GIF, of the 'nasty visual effect' occurring.  Someone might recognize it.

Comment: It's just a mesh being reduced with time (lifetime of a particle) - the smaller it gets, it seems the less vertices it is comprise of

Comment: How complex are the meshes (how many verts each?), and how many meshes are you spawning in the particle effect?

Comment: Meshes are simple, they suppose to simulate smoke (one mesh/particle is equal to 120 triangles, 360 indices)

Comment: Ok, as long as there aren't 200+ particles in the system at any given time, batching doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: It works fine with lower end Android's devices and weirdly enough it fails on higher, even Samsung S-line

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the scale of my game (game's unit is small in this case). But this might've cause the issues with physics engine rather then graphical rasterization

Comment: @AlexM. Could you take a look at UPDATE 2 description? Any ideas?

Comment: So normally they were going from size 1 down to 0, and this was causing issues.  Now, you're starting at size 5 and going down to 0?

Comment: Now I'm sizing them down from 5 to around 1 (I use the graphical fn of Unity's IDE) and as a result they're covering most of mobile's screen space but at least I'm not seeing any reduction in their mesh, any glitches whatsoever

Comment: Huh.  I don't know enough about Unity's particle system + meshes or the Andriod platform get why that would happen on certain devices.  Assuming it happens when you scale from 5 to 0, it sounds like it has something to do with approaching zero-scale.  It's beyond my pay grade, for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track the issue down. It turned out to be a problem within a toon shader I wrote while a go. All the things I've noticed are valid but unfortunately it took some time to put me on the right track.

Taken from Unity's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DataTypesAndPrecision.html)

> The half and fixed types only become relevant when targeting mobile
> GPUs, where these types primarily exist for power (and sometimes
> performance) constraints. Keep in mind that you need to test your
> shaders on mobile to see whether or not you are running into
> precision/numerical issues.

Unfortunately for me, as it cost me quite some time, I've used half3/4 values with POSITION semantics which caused some **numerical precision issues** on some Android devices (in this case the particles were getting smaller and smaller - size 0 to be exact). As a general rule, from what I've read in Unity's documentation, float3/4 should always be preferred in conjunction with POSITION semantics.